# How do I uninstall Google Chrome *completely* from my Mac?

Tags: mac, google-chrome, osx-lion

I have 2 iMacs and just installed OS X Lion (clean install) on one of them (let's call it iMac A). Did a time machine backup and restored that backup to my other iMac (B) to avoid installing twice. Everything works perfectly except that Google Chrome is extremely slow on iMac B (where the time machine backup was restored to). Opening a new tab is slow, opening a web page is slow etc. Safari on B is fast and works like on A, so it's just on B that Chrome is slow (and Chrome is my preferred browser, so I'd like to get it up to speed).

To solve the problem on B, I've tried uninstalling Chrome by dragging it to the Trashcan and emptying it. Then re-installg Chrome. But all my settings, extensions etc. are still there and it's just as slow as before.

Downloaded AppCleaner and did an uninstall with that, but still, when I re-install Chrome I have all my extensions etc. and it is as slow as before the re-install.

Does anyone know how to completely uninstall my Google Chrome browser so I can do a fresh install of it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Delete this:

> user>library>application support>google>chrome .. just delete the chrome folder since I think its the place where they keep the settings.

[Source](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=374fc0730749b130&hl=en)

Comment: I think it means to uninstall, then remove the folder, then re-install.

Comment: Thought I'd tried that but just tried and it worked. Thanks :-)  PS. SU wants me to wait 7 mins before I can accept the answer, so hold on, please - and thanks again :)

Comment: Not a problem :). It would also be appreciated if you would upvote it once you have enough rep.

Comment: Will do. You should think they'd transfer rep from Stack Overflow (where I have enough) but it seems these sites are treated separately with regards to reputation. PS. Deleting the directory and re-installing didn't solve my problem with it being slow. Any ideas why?

Comment: Ask another question, don't know off the top of my head. If you have enough rep, when you get an account on a new SE site, you start with 101.

Comment: Guess I don't have enough then :)   OK; will ask another question. Thanks :)

Comment: This worked! Great post!!!

Answer (score 60):

Here's a shell script that removes all files I could find:

```
rm -r /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/
rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/
rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/CrashReporter/Google\ Chrome*
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome*
rm ~/Library/Preferences/Google\ Chrome*
rm -r ~/Library/Caches/com.google.Chrome*
rm -r ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.google.Chrome.savedState/
rm ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/Actives/com.google.Chrome
rm ~/Library/Google/Google\ Chrome*
rm -r ~/Library/Speech/Speakable\ Items/Application\ Speakable\ Items/Google\ Chrome/
```

AppZapper and App Cleaner didn't find the application support folder:

[image]
[image]

Comment: +1 This is the answer you want if you're trying to COMPLETELY remove Chrome. Was having some weird rendering issues, but reinstalling from scratch appears to have resolved it

Comment: Thanks for pointing out AppZapper and AppCleaner. For those that see this, AppCleaner did a much better job of finding other files that should be removed and I added them to the list above.

Comment: +1.  I also found `~/Library/Google/Google\ Chrome\ Brand.plist`.

Comment: Also: `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.google.keystone.agent.plist`, `~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Keystone.Agent.plist`, `~/Library/Caches/com.google.Keystone*`, `~/Library/Caches/com.google.SoftwareUpdate`, `~/Library/Application Support/Google/RLZ`

Comment: wow, thats a lot of to do to remove chrome. lol  I found another one , prettify.js does it related to chrome. I search for google.

Comment: Is there any reason why I should not remove the entire dir `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/`?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `user495470`'s comment, do `rm -rf ~/Applications/Chrome\ Apps`, where plugins ("apps") are stored by the browser.

Comment: for me this dir was empty, all were stored in `/Applications/Crhome\ Apps`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1. At the bottom of your computer screen, in your Dock, right-click Chrome.
2. Select Quit.
3. Open Finder.
4. Go to the folder containing the Google Chrome application on your computer.

   - Tip: It may be in your Applications folder. If not, go to File and then Find, and search for "Google Chrome."
5. Drag Google Chrome to the Trash.
6. Optional: Delete your profile information, like bookmarks and history:

   - At the top of the screen, click Go and then Go to Folder.
   - Enter `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome.`
   - Click Go.
   - Select all the folders, and drag them to the Trash.

Source from official docs: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95319?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

you can run this on terminal

```
rm -rf /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/
rm /Library/LaunchAgents/com.google.keystone*
rm -rf /Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome*

rm -rf ~/Applications/Chrome\ Apps.localized/
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.google.keystone*
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome*
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/CrashReporter/Google\ Chrome
rm ~/Library/Preferences/Google\ Chrome*
rm -r ~/Library/Caches/com.google.Chrome*
rm -r ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.google.Chrome.savedState/
rm ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/Actives/com.google.Chrome
rm ~/Library/Google/Google\ Chrome*
```

or you could use [mac_chrome_uninstaller](https://github.com/wendyliga/mac_chrome_uninstaller)