# Chrome keeps crashing on Mavericks

Tags: macos, google-chrome, crash, osx-mavericks

I updated my OS X to Mavericks a while ago, and Google Chrome keeps crashing constantly.
I tried the following but none of them worked:

- Cleared cache and cookies
- Removed my user profile and added a user again
- Disabled/Removed all extensions
- Updated Chrome to latest version twice. 30 & 31.

This is the .crash file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16657557/Google%20Chrome_2013-11-18-202242_sallars-mac.crash

I can’t find the reason why it keeps crashing.
Can anyone help me with this? I searched a lot on google, nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: You could try to [remove Chrome support files](http://superuser.com/questions/318186) and reinstall Chrome.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Start this weekend. Chrome has become unusable now. I've temporarily switched to Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X 10.9.1 Update solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it work finally with 10.9.1. Here is what I did:

1. Launch a terminal window

   ```
   sudo rm /var/root/Library/LaunchAgents/com.google.keystone.agent.plist
   cd /Applications/Google\ Chrome
   sudo ./Google\ Chrome
   ```
2. when Chome is running go to extensions, remove Google Docs.
3. Quit Chrome
4. Now Chrome should be able to run normally from the Finder

I hope it will also work for you guys

Comment: You definitely shouldn't start Chrome with `sudo` - there's no reason to do that. If you do, Chrome will write all new files during that session as root user.